# How is GPU affinity decided in a Multi-GPU configuration?

Tags: windows-7, multiple-monitors, gpu

In a Win 7 system with multiple different video cards (NON-SLI and NON-CROSSFIRE), how is decided GPU affinity?

So you have 2 totally different video cards, each with it's own display and you launch a 3D app (a game). On which GPU is gonna run? Can you control GPU affinity?

Comment: By "Totally Different" do you mean 2 nVidia, 2 AMD/ATI, a combination of the two, or other GPU cards?

Comment: @bobSmith1432 Let's say one AMD and one nVidia, so no bridging technology.

Comment: @user1410908 - Because they are not linked you can no performance increase from having a Nvidia and an AMD GPU in your system. Even if they were both Nvidia if they are not link you still would not recieve any performance benefit from having two GPUs

Comment: Unless programmed to behave otherwise, it'll launch on your "Primary" display device.

Comment: @techie007 You are right. I just found out that everything is rendered on primary (unless the app is programed otherwise) and displayed on whichever screen by copying the frame buffer to the corresponding card. So all the work is done by the primary card, and the second card would just "relay" the rendered image to the second screen.